# Scheduling playback of AudioWorkletNode

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I'm working with [soundtouchjs-audio-worklet](https://github.com/cutterbl/soundtouchjs-audio-worklet) in order to change the tempo/pitch of audio files that have been read into a buffer. The library creates a worklet that can process these buffers, and gives me an `AudioWorkletNode` to control it. What I need to do is schedule the playback of multiple `AudioWorkletNode`s so that different audio files can be on a "timeline" of sorts.

I know the `AudioBufferSourceNode` has a `when` parameter in it's `start()` function that you can use to schedule the playback of the node. But `AudioWorkletNode` doesn't seem to be scheduleable; it just immediately begins playback upon `connect()`ing it.

I could use `setTimeout()` to delay calling `connect()`, but I don't think the timing will be accurate enough. Does anyone know of a way to schedule playback of an `AudioWorkletNode`? Or an accurate way to connect it at the exact right time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to schedule an `AudioWorkletProcessor` but it's possible to use the global `currentTime` variable to build it yourself. The processor would then look a bit like this.

```
class ScheduledProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.port.onmessage = (event) => this.startTime = event.data;
        this.startTime = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }

    process() {
        if (currentTime < this.startTime) {
            return true;
        }

        // Now it's time to start the processing.
    }
}

registerProcessor('scheduled-processor', ScheduledProcessor);
```

It can then be "scheduled" to start when `currentTime` is 15 like this:

```
const scheduledAudioNode = new AudioWorkletNode(
    audioContext,
    'scheduled-processor'
);

scheduledAudioNode.port.postMessage(15);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about the `currentTime` global variable that's available inside AudioWorkletProcessors!